# convert a DataFrame into a string in scala

Tags: hive

I am trying to download the Hive jar in sbt and I am getting the following error. Have anyone encountered this?

please let me know what is the correct hive version I need to create a GenericUDF class

This is my SBT file

```
name := "Test"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"


libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-exec" % "1.2.1"
```

The below is the error message I am getting

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>[error]   at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:118)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2353)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:257)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:266)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:257)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:167)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:32)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (*:update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.pentaho#pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm;5.1.5-jhyde: not found
[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.pentaho#pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm;5.1.5-jhyde: not found
[error] Total time: 20 s, completed Oct 11, 2017 4:27:03 PM</pre><br/>See complete log in <a href="file:/Users/spachari/Library/Logs/IdeaIC2017.2/sbt.last.log">file:/Users/spachari/Library/Logs/IdeaIC2017.2/sbt.last.log</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using below SBT, it should help.

name := "Test"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8" libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.hive" % "hive-exec" % "1.2.1").map(_.exclude("org.pentaho", "pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm"))